# Planner API : MS Graph Application Permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I am trying to integrate Planner with a custom app. I tried the API's in Graph Explorer and it works well.

But when I try to use an Application token and try the Planner API, it is giving me 403 error. Then I saw that the Planner API doesn't support Application permissions yet.

Is there any workaround around this ? or is there any timeline when the Planner API will support Application Permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

Application permissions are now supported. You should also check out [Business Scenarios API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/businessscenarios-concept-overview) which has more powerful functionality and control for integration type scenarios (e.g. you want to have data you have to show up as tasks)

Outdated reply:

> Please see:
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/announcing-updates-to-the-planner-api-in-microsoft-graph/
>
> Before it is available the only available workaround is to create an
> account to be used by the app and add it to every group as a member.
> We're looking into adding Application Permissions, specifically for
> read operations, but I can't provide a timeline for when this will be
> available.